Multiple destination repos to push from forked repo
I have the following.
    Base Repo
    - main

    MyFork Repo (from Base Repo)
    - main
    - feature A
    - feature B

    AnotherFork Repo (from Base Repo)
    - main
    - feature C

I have forked MyFork Repo from Base Repo. That works fine. Now I'm interesting in the feature C branch from AnotherFork Repo. I can't fork AnotherFork Repo because I already forked Base Repo.
I also can't just clone AnotherFork Repo and create branches there or push to feature C. That is just with PRs possible.
Can I do then i.e. something like that?
    MyFork Repo
    - main
    - feature A (is linked to Base Repo)
    - feature B (is linked to Base Repo)
    - feature C (is linked to AnotherFork Repo)

Or do I have to delete MyFork Repo and create then a fork to AnotherFork Repo?

I don't know about forking rules... but git does not care abour forks. It cares about remotes..... and it actually works on commits and does not care where they are coming from.... so if you have a local repo where you can get visibility of those repos as remotes, then you can shuffle stuff around anyway you want to put any branch on any remote (as long as you havce permissions in the remote, of course).

Forking rules say me that I can't fork the second one because I have already a fork from the main one.

When you talk about a "fork", do you mean a repository at the hoster, such as Github, or do you actually mean the clone of the repository that you have locally?

When you say "I am interested in feature C", do you mean "I want to use it as basis for my work", or do you mean "this stuff is so great, I want to publish it unmodified in MyFork as if it were my work"?

It's a Github fork. I can just contribute to the main repo via fork and PR to the main one. Feature C is something I want to contribute but that is at the moment still in another repo which forked also the main one but that branch is at the moment no part of the main one. I can also just contribute to them with a PR.

There are two typical workflows: central and distributed.
Central repository

In this workflow, there is a central / "official" repository from all other pull and push. In this workflow, you'd push feature/C from AnotherFork to Base and then pull feature/C from Base to MyFork.
$ cd AnotherFork
$ git push feature/C

$ cd MyFork
$ git fetch && git switch feature/C

Distributed repositories

In this workflow, some repositories know others as remotes, and you can directly pull feature/C from AnotherFork to MyFork.
$ cd MyFork
$ git remote add AnotherFork proto://url/AnotherFork
$ git fetch AnotherFork
$ git switch remotes/AnotherFork/feature/C

Additional reading

man git-remote
man git-fetch
man git-branch
2.5 Git Basics - Working with Remotes
5.1 Distributed Git - Distributed Workflows


The distributed workflow seems to be the one I need. I'll try it in the next days when I continue with the project. Thanks

The distributed workflow was what I needed and it worked perfectly. Thank you. :)

Happy for you! You'll be a remote expert in no time ;)
